# How can I upload Image ftp server asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, iis, ftp

I want to upload image by using ftp account. My code is like this. But when I choose image and submit, It says me "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\picture.jpg'." I know my image is on my desktop and I choose from there. If I copy my image manually this IIS folder, it will upload but this is not sensible. I must choose my image where I want.  But it is looking for in IIS Express folder.

```
      [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Insert(Press model, HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
    {
       ...........
       ...........
       ...........
       ...........

            if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadfile.FileName);
                var fileInf = new FileInfo(fileName);
                var reqFtp =
                    (FtpWebRequest)
                        FtpWebRequest.Create(
                            new Uri("ftp://ftp.adres.com" + fileInf.Name));
                reqFtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                reqFtp.KeepAlive = false;
                reqFtp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                reqFtp.UseBinary = true;
                reqFtp.ContentLength = uploadfile.ContentLength;
                int bufferlength = 2048;
                byte[] buff = new byte[bufferlength];
                int contentLen;
                FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();

                try
                {
                    Stream strm = reqFtp.GetRequestStream();
                    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, bufferlength);
                    while (contentLen != 0)
                    {
                        strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, bufferlength);
                    }
                    strm.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            }
       ...........
       ...........
       ...........
       ...........
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the value in fileName is what you are expecting here:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadfile.FileName);
```

You most likely need to pass the path as a string, as well as the filename into the Combine method.

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(varFilePath, uploadfile.FileName);
```

Path.Combine expects an array of strings to combine: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to ask one more thing. How can I get the file path. The file may be desktop or elsewhere

Comment: The SaveAs Method on HttpPostedFile will allow you to pass it a string to save the file the client uploaded. [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution for my problem and I want to share here, maybe a person can benefit

```
 void UploadToFtp(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
    {
        var uploadurl = "ftp://ftp.adress.com/";
        var uploadfilename = uploadfile.FileName;
        var username = "ftpusername";
        var password = "ftppassword";
        Stream streamObj = uploadfile.InputStream;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[uploadfile.ContentLength];
        streamObj.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        streamObj.Close();
        streamObj = null;
        string ftpurl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", uploadurl, uploadfilename);
        var requestObj = FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpurl) as FtpWebRequest;
        requestObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        requestObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        Stream requestStream = requestObj.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        requestStream.Flush();
        requestStream.Close();
        requestObj = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How to upload file by ftp using Asp.net MVC.

**View**

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="postedFile" name="postedFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="send"  />
    </form>
```

**Controller ActionResult**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        //FTP Server URL.
        string ftp = "ftp://ftp.YourServer.com/";
        //FTP Folder name. Leave blank if you want to upload to root folder.
        string ftpFolder = "test/";
        byte[] fileBytes = null;
        string ftpUserName = "YourUserName";
        string ftpPassword = "YourPassword";
        //Read the FileName and convert it to Byte array.
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
        {
            fileBytes = br.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);
        }
        try
        {
            //Create FTP Request.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp + ftpFolder + fileName);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            //Enter FTP Server credentials.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
            request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
            request.EnableSsl = false;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception((ex.Response as FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

For upload large files you can add this line to your web.config
*Thanks to [Karthik Ganesan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562424/karthik-ganesan)*

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="whatever value you need in kb max value is 2,147,483,647 kb" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

under system.web section the default is 4 mb size limit